# How can I reset the timer in a timer based on the react-countdown component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and javascript. I am trying to implement a timer in my webpage. How do I implement the reset() function which is called when the "Reset Clock" button is clicked? I am expecting the timer to be reset to the initial value. Please provide suggestions for implementing the reset function.

This is the code that I am using:

### App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Clock from './CountDown';

class App extends React.Component {
    clockRef = null;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setClockRef = this.setClockRef.bind(this);
        this.start = this.start.bind(this);
        this.pause = this.pause.bind(this);
        this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
    }

    start() {
        this.clockRef.start();
    }
    pause() {
        this.clockRef.pause();
    }
    reset() {
    }

    setClockRef(ref) {
        // When the `Clock` (and subsequently `Countdown` mounts
        // this will give us access to the API
        this.clockRef = ref;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <button onClick={this.start}>Start Clock</button>
                <button onClick={this.pause}>Pause Clock</button>
                <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset Clock</button>
                <Clock refCallback={this.setClockRef} time="60" />
            </>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

### CountDown.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Countdown from 'react-countdown';

export default class Clock extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { refCallback, time } = this.props;

        return (
            <Countdown
                // When the component mounts, this will
                // call `refCallback` in the parent component,
                // passing a reference to this `Countdown` component
                key = {0}
                ref={refCallback}
                date={Date.now() + (time * 60000)}
                intervalDelay={3}
                zeroPadTime={2}
                autoStart={false}
                daysInHours
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this example from the `react-countdown` repo that implements start, pause and reset: https://github.com/ndresx/react-countdown/blob/c909d9746bc79cdc9b8866d98284b0256d643a1a/examples/src/CountdownApi.tsx

In that example they reset the countdown by holding the `date` in state and updating it to do a reset.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the github project. I adopted the code in it. I am able to add a reset functionality to the timer.